# Isolate Wireless Subnet

Tags: wireless-networking

I need to configure my wireless router so that all users connected to the router cannot access my internal network. Below is my network configuration. At this moment users in 192.168.29.0/24 subnet can access 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. Is is possible to prevent communications between the two subnets using this configuration?

```
                                Internet
                                   |
                                 Modem
                                   |
                                Gateway
                                   |
              ---------------------------------------------  192.168.1.0/24
              |         |          |          |           |
             PC1       PC2        PC3      Wireless      PC4
                                            Router
                                          (WAN Port)
                                              |
                                       ----------------  192.168.29.0/24
                                       |      |       |
                                      PC5    PC6     PC7
```

Comment: Normally, you would have a single router with one router port connected to the wired network and one router port connected to a WAP. Then you can put in an ACL to prevent traffic from the wireless network leaving out the wired router port.